# Recovery mode. Терминал

Tags: macos, консоль, recovery

Куда я попадаю, и чьи Файлы просматриваю в терминале, зайдя в recovery mode? Если файлы не моего пользователя (админа), то как увидеть свои?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Своих файлов вы не увидите, т.к. раздел зашифрован. Но его можно подключить. Для этого надо выполнить:

```
diskutil list
```

Затем в списке найти lvUUID своего раздела и выполнить команду:

```
diskutil cs unlockVolume lvUUID
```

Далее вас спросят пароль пользователя для расшифровки. После успешного расшифровывания раздел появится в папке Volumes.
подробнее тут: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/236206/backup-files-from-terminal-in-recovery-mode